# 2D array or 2D slice for Tic-Tac-Toe board?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I started to learn GoLang and meet trouble. When i tried to pass array (which size is defined after enter them from output) to the function a get error like "sorry but you type [][]string is not like [][]string". I tried different ways but can't cope with it. Any suggestions?

There is the main func:

```
func main(){
fmt.Println("Enter number of rows: ")
fmt.Scanf("%d", &size)
var board [size][size]string
for i:=0;i<size;i++{
    for j:=0;j<size;j++{
        board[i][j] = "_"
    }
}
fmt.Println("Choose side of fight (X, 0): ")
fmt.Scanf("%s", &opt)
fmt.Printf("Your side is %s\n", opt)
for !win{
    printBoard(board, size)
    fmt.Println("Your move(a b, \"a\" is number of row, \"b\" is number of column: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &move[0], &move[1])
    if move[0]>=1 && move[1]>=1 && move[0]<=3 && move[1]<=3{
        board[move[0]-1][move[1]-1] = opt
    }
    bot(&board, size)
    win, winner = checkWin(board, opt, size)
}
}
```

And example of function which depart take array:

```
func printBoard(in [][]string, size int){
for k:=0;k<size+1;k++{
    fmt.Printf("%d\t", k)
}
fmt.Println()
    for i:=0;i<size;i++{
        fmt.Printf("%d ", i+1)
    for j:=0;j<size;j++     {
        fmt.Printf("\t%s", in[i][j])
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")
}
fmt.Print("\n")
}
```

The ouput that I am trying to achieve is for Tic/Tac toe game. for eg:-

```
Enter number of rows: 3 Choose side of fight (X, 0): X 
Your side is X  0   1   2   3   1 _ _   _ 2 _   _   _ 3 _   _   _ 
Your move(a b, "a" is number of row, "b" is number of column: 1 1 0 1   2   3   1 X _   _ 2 _   _   _ 3 _   _   _ 
Your move(a b, "a" is number of row, "b" is number of column: 2 2 0 1   2   3   1 X _   _ 2 _   X   _ 3 _   _   _ 
Your move(a b, "a" is number of row, "b" is number of column: 3 3 0 1   2   3   1 X _   _ 2 _   X   _ 3 _   _   X You're winner!!!
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use Go arrays. Array size is a compile-time constant. An array, the entire array, is passed by value as an argument to a function parameter or receiver.

Use slices. Declare a slice-based `Board` type. Give the type a set of methods; pass that type as the method receiver.

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Board [][]string // [rows][cols]

func NewBoard(rows, cols int) Board {
    b := make([][]string, rows)
    for r := range b {
        b[r] = make([]string, cols)
    }
    return Board(b)
}

func (b Board) Rows() int {
    return len(b)
}

func (b Board) Cols() int {
    if len(b) == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return len(b[0])
}

func (b Board) Print() {
    maxWidth := 0
    for r := range b {
        for c := range b[r] {
            if width := len(b[r][c]); maxWidth < width {
                maxWidth = width
            }
        }
    }
    width := maxWidth + 2
    for r := range b {
        for c := range b[r] {
            fmt.Printf("%-*s", width, b[r][c])
        }
        fmt.Printf("\n")
    }
}

func main() {
    rows, cols := 3, 2 // input from user?
    board := NewBoard(rows, cols)

    for r := range board {
        for c := range board[r] {
            board[r][c] = fmt.Sprintf("[R%d, C%d]", r, c)
        }
    }
    board.Print()

    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n%v %v\n%v\n",
        board,
        board.Rows(), board.Cols(),
        board[1][1],
    )
}
```

Output:

```
[R0, C0]  [R0, C1]  
[R1, C0]  [R1, C1]  
[R2, C0]  [R2, C1]  

[[[R0, C0] [R0, C1]] [[R1, C0] [R1, C1]] [[R2, C0] [R2, C1]]]
3 2
[R1, C1]
```

---

References:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Answer (score 2):

In Go `[]string` is a slice and `[42]string` is an array. Those types are very different.

See https://blog.golang.org/slices

In this case you should use slices as the board is of variable size.

```
board := make([][]string, size)
for i:=0;i<size;i++{
    board[i] = make([]string, size)
    for j:=0;j<size;j++{
        board[i][j] = "_"
    }
}
```

Comment: OK i know it now, but what should i do in this state. When i need array but i don't know it's size before than user input it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing an array when calling `printBoard` function but in function definition you have passed `Slice` as an argument that's why the error of `type mismatch`. So my suggestion will be you can pass slice to the `printBoard` function.

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter number of rows: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &size)
    var board [][]string
    board = make([][]string, size, (2*size)+1)

    fmt.Println("Choose side of fight (X, 0): ")
    var opt int
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &opt)
    fmt.Printf("Your side is %s\n", opt)
    var win bool
    for !win {
        printBoard(board, size)
        fmt.Println("Your move(a b, \"a\" is number of row, \"b\" is number of column: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &move[0], &move[1])
        if move[0] >= 1 && move[1] >= 1 && move[0] <= 3 && move[1] <= 3 {
            board[move[0]-1][move[1]-1] = opt
        }
        bot(&board, size)
        win, winner = checkWin(board, opt, size)
    }
}
```

For more information on Slice Check [Go Slices: usage and internals blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Comment: Ok, i had [][]string. But now i need an array with number of rows and columns which user define before it begin

Comment: @daniktl Need not to have an array, you can calculate `length` everytime a player make a chess move or append to the slice for every move player take

Comment: @daniktl Also why do you need an array. I think chess has fixed length.If you are asking for the move a player takes create a separate slice with row and column value

Comment: Chess yes, but Tic-tac-toe not. Basic version was created 3x3. But now i want to make it variable (3x3, 4x4, 5x5 and so on).

Comment: Enter number of rows: 
3
Choose side of fight (X, 0): 
X
Your side is X
0 1 2 3 
1  _ _ _
2  _ _ _
3  _ _ _

Your move(a b, "a" is number of row, "b" is number of column: 
1 1
0 1 2 3 
1  X _ _
2  _ _ _
3  _ _ _

Your move(a b, "a" is number of row, "b" is number of column: 
2 2
0 1 2 3 
1  X _ _
2  _ X _
3  _ _ _

Your move(a b, "a" is number of row, "b" is number of column: 
3 3
0 1 2 3 
1  X _ _
2  _ X _
3  _ _ X

You're winner!!!!

Comment: Please edit your question and add this comment it will help user to know what you are trying to achieve.